# Show that $\int_{x^2}^{x}\frac{g(t)}{\ln t}dt+\ln2=\frac{x(x-1)(x+2)}{2}g(x)-\int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{1+2t}{t}g(t)dt$

Tags: integration

where $g(x)=\frac{x-1}{\ln(x)}$ for all $x>1$ and $g(1)=1$

I know this is too specific but I need to prove that using integration by parts and  $ln2=\int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{1}{t\ln t}dt$

Answer (score 0):

With $u=\ln(t)$, the integral has the form

$$\int_{\ln(x)}^{\ln(x^2)}\frac{u'}{u}=$$

$$\Bigl[\frac{u}{u}\Bigr]_{\ln(x)}^{\ln(x^2)}-\int_{\ln(x)}^{\ln(x^2)}u\frac{-u'}{u^2}=$$

$$\Bigl[\ln(u)\Bigr]_{\ln(x)}^{\ln(x^2)}=$$
$$\ln(\ln(x^2))-\ln(\ln(x))=\ln(2)$$

Comment: Can you explain what you just did? (which integral you integrated by parts after that substitution?) I am lost. // Nevermind I got it! You showed that: $$\ln2=\int_{x}^{x^2}\frac{1}{t\ln t}dt$$ But that it's already given.

Comment: @Zacky the third line is a by parts integration of $u' 1/u$.